# Adding categories & subcategories to a blog

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Ok, I have done lots of research and looked at lots of stackoverflow questions but none have answered my question.

I'm building a simple blog and am at the moment i'm trying to build a simple categories/subcategories system but have hit an obstacle in making the subcategories load under their parent. If you know an easier method to the one i am doing below please let me know.

Here is how my db is structured:

```
id || name || parent_id || status
------------------------------------------
1  || category1 || NULL || 1
2  || subcategory1 || 1 || 1
```

Then i have my model code:

```
public function getCategories()
{
    $results = $this->db->select('msi_items_categories','status = 1 AND parent_id = NULL');
    if( !is_array($results[0]) ) {
        $new_results = array();
        array_push($new_results, $results);
        return $new_results;
    } else {
        return $results;
    }
}

public function getSubCategories($parent)
{
    $bind = [':parent' => $parent];
    $results = $this->db->select('msi_items_categories','status = 1 AND parent_id = :parent');
    if( !is_array($results[0]) ) {
        $new_results = array();
        array_push($new_results, $results);
        return $new_results;
    } else {
        return $results;
    }
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function error()
{
    $getSettings = $this->setting->getAll();
    $getCategories = $this->setting->getCategories();
    $getSubCategories = $this->setting->getSubCategories();
    if(is_array($getCategories[0]) ) {
        $isCategory = true;
    } else {
        $isCategory = false;
    }
    if(is_array($getSubCategories[0]) ) {
        $isSubCategory = true;
    } else {
        $isSubCategory = false;
    }
    $data = [
        'settings' => $getSettings,
        'mainCategory' => $getCategories,
        'subCategory' => $getSubCategories,
        'isCategory' => $isCategory
        'isSubCategory' => $isSubCategory
    ];
    $this->view('index', $data);
}
```

Then I have my templatecode which is where im trying to do the foreach and the top category works fine but i just can't figure out how i do the subcategories. Before i started using the MVC model, i would simply just put the class inside the main category foreach and then put the id but now its all done in the controller so i cannot figure out how i do subcategories using the MVC model.

```
    <?php foreach($data['mainCategory'] as $category) : ?>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link dropdown-toggle pl-0" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" role="presentation" href="#"><i class="text-black-50 fas fa-box"></i>&nbsp; All <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider" role="presentation"></div>
            <?php foreach($data['subCategory'] as $scategory) : ?>
                <a class="dropdown-item" role="presentation" href="#"><i class="text-black-50 <?php echo $scategory['icon']; ?>"></i>&nbsp; <?php echo $scategory['name']; ?></a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: It is best approach you are implementing.

Comment: Ok thanks but how would you recommend i get the subcategory? It won't echo! I'm stuck on how to make it so that the subcategory goes below its parent. Right now i get the top categories but the dropdown is just a bunch of errors.

Comment: What are the errors that you got?

Comment: The *tidiest* way I've found the do this is to build the navigation up as XML (using DOMDocument); that way you can do it all in one query if you order by `parent_id ASC` - you just loop through and create an `id` attribute of each node then, if a category has a `parent_id`, you assign it to the node with the corresponding `id` attribute. That way everything is structured the way you want for output no matter how deep the category structure is.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh this is the error: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/456742636653641728/459081315262791706/unknown.png - the error is because i have not specified a parent id but i dont know how to as its in the controller. So basically here $getSubCategories = $this->setting->getSubCategories($parent_id); but i don't know how to get the parent id from the controller.

Comment: This error clearly means that `subCategory` doesn't exist in `$category` variable.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh please read updated comment

Comment: @CD001 would you be able to write a simple example of what you mean? Thanks

Comment: @LovepreetSingh I literally just want to make it so that the subcategory automatically goes below its parent but as i can't get the parent id from the controller i'm unsure how to go about it.

Comment: What does your controller actually get? The *sub-category* id?

Comment: @CD001 basically there are two models, first one is for top categories, second one is for subcategories but that second model only works when i can put a parent id in it so it will be like this if it worked.     $getCategories = $this->setting->getCategories();
    $getSubCategories = $this->setting->getSubCategories($parent_id); so then these parent id's match up to the top id but my issue that i cannot figure out is how i call the parent id from the controller...

Comment: @CD001 because i can not do what i used to do where i call the class inside the foreach and then base it off of the first foreach variable id etc. so im just a bit confused and need some php expertise to help me get the subcategories working. The top categories work fine just the sub that need fixing.

Comment: I think you are trying to kill a mole with a hammer. I can't assist with MVC but if you simply want to end up with a PHP array containing the hierarchy of categories (not limited to 2 levels) - you can use a clever trick with variable references (http://blog.ideashower.com/post/15147134343/create-a-parent-child-array-structure-in-one-pass)

Comment: @IVOGELOV its ok i figured out a better way to do it. I basically built a function in a helper where in the view file i sent the parent variable and id and now it works great! https://gyazo.com/d984f5fa92396a8ca358df65c0e98b09  / https://gyazo.com/665a321172a1fee688be9191d438540d but could i ask you a question about how you think i could achieve a feature where if no children are found then do not show dropdown arrow? Thanks

Comment: @BobMars You should change the `sub()` function to return the template as a string instead of directly echo-ing - then you will only show a dropdown arrow if this string is not empty.

Comment: @IVOGELOV like this? https://gyazo.com/e490b9f9f37b3224bf8b027059f0cc53 but then it just does not load in on the front end so am i missing something there? https://gyazo.com/6ef54ef219961307e79fd93a7f2d20a1

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT id, parent_id, name, icon FROM categories ORDER BY name';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) OR trigger_error($query.'<br>'.mysqli_error($conn),E_USER_ERROR);

$refs = Array();
$categories = Array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $thisref = &$refs[$row['id']];
  $thisref['name'] = $row['name'];
  $thisref['icon'] = $row['icon'];
  if($row['parent_id']) $refs[$row['parent_id']]['children'][$row['id']] = &$thisref;
    else $categories[$row['id']] = &$thisref;
}

echo '<ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">';
foreach($categories as $category)
{
  echo '<li class="dropdown">';
  echo is_array($category['children'])
    ? '<a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link dropdown-toggle pl-0" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">'.$category['name'].'</a>'.sub($category['children'])
    : $category['name'];
  echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

function sub(&$subCat)
{
  echo '<div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item hide-me" role="presentation" href="#"><i class="fas fa-fire mr-2"></i> Most Popular </a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider hide-me" role="presentation"></div>';
  foreach($subCat as $id => $subcategory)
  {
    echo '<a class="dropdown-item" role="presentation" href="'.FULL_ROOT.'/category/'.$id.'/"><i class="'.$subcategory['icon'].' mr-2"></i>'.$subcategory['name'].'</a>';
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
```